# How to show Blinking gms marker on gmsmap view?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using **google map** , and I have used **GMS Map view**.In map view I have created one **GMS marker** for current location and it is updating every one second with current latitude and longitude value.I used this code:

```
mMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc]init];
mMapView.delegate = self;
mMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mMapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 95, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height -205);

GMSMarker *disMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinateEndLocation];
disMarker.snippet = @"current Location";
disMarker.animated = YES;
disMarker.map = mMapView;
```

But I want that this marker should be **blinking** in every second and this one in not blinking.Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

GMSMarker doesn't by default provides a blinking marker.. you have to create 1 by yourself.. You can try blinking marker by using a timer and changing the opacity property of your marker between 0 and 1.. `- (float) opacity [read, write, assign]` have a look on this property of your GMSMarker

Comment: I have tried to do it but I am unable to figure this out.Can you give me any link or sample code.

Comment: there is no sample code for this.. you have to figure out yourself how to do this..